How to verify refresh_token using Firebase/JWT?
I have a simple endpoint called signIn.php that have a function to generate a refresh_token:
define('REFRESH_SECRET', 'my-009-secret');

function generateRefreshToken() {
    $randomBytes = random_bytes(32);
    $refreshToken = hash('sha256', $randomBytes . REFRESH_SECRET);
    return $refreshToken;
}

This functions returns a hash code that I stores in a cookie:
$refreshToken = generateRefreshToken();

setcookie('refreshToken', $refreshToken, [
    'expires' => time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
    'path' => '/api-tokens',
    'domain' => '', 
    'secure' => true, 
    'httponly' => true, 
    'samesite' => 'None'
]);

Beyond this endpoint, I have another called refreshUser.php that is used to generate another access_token to my application. Since this endpoint will only be called when my user's access_token is invalid, I need to check the refresh_token, for this, I need to get my cookie and check if It's valid first:
define('REFRESH_SECRET', 'my-009-secret');

$expectedRefreshToken = hash('sha256', $_COOKIE['refreshToken'] . REFRESH_SECRET);
$decoded = JWT::decode($refreshToken, new Key($expectedRefreshToken, 'HS256'));

The problem is that I am receiving the following error message:

Wrong number of segments

How can I solve this problem? I'm using this library.
